# Inconsistent 403 Forbidden issues with images on a website

Tags: http, iis-8.5

I am getting inconsistent HTTP 403 Forbidden results when requesting images embedded on a webpage. This is happening more frequently in FireFox, but occasionally also happens in Chrome. This website has been used for many years and this just popped up a few weeks ago. I control both the website and the server and am not sure of how to troubleshoot this issue. When I refresh the page it seems to be a different combination of resources that causes the issue.

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains;
P3P: Our site does not have a P3P Policy, please see our privacy policy for more information.
Date: Fri, 15 Apr 2022 17:34:15 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Request:

```
GET /bonds/images/exclamation.png HTTP/1.1
Host: <Redacted>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,*/*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: <Redacted>
Cookie: <Redacted>
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 04 Apr 2022 20:03:08 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Comment: It's just 1 server? No load-balancer sending some traffic to a wrong backend? Have you enabled server logging?: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/configure-logging-in-iis

Comment: Focus on the whom what and when to start with. Does _everyone_ get 403s at the same time? If so, what times? (scan your logs for timestamps) When does it start working again? Are _some_ users are getting them _all_ of the time? Is it only specific images? Understanding the pattern can point you in the right direction. Perhaps some built-in rate-limiting on resource or source IP?

Comment: You really need the help of FRT to learn more about the 403 errors, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Without that no serious discussion can be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it appears the issue was being caused by the dynamic IP restrictions limit, and increasing the max concurrent requests solved the issue.